# Symbolic double summation vs nested summations

Tags: summation

Take the following code:

```
Simplify[
  Sum[
    Sum[
      ((-1)^(1 + q1 + q2) 2^(-2 q1 - 2 q2) q2 Theta^(1 + 2 q1 + 2 q2))/((1 + 2 q1)! (2 q2)!), 
      {q1, 0, Infinity}], 
    {q2, 0, Infinity}]]

Simplify[
  Sum[
    ((-1)^(1 + q1 + q2) 2^(-2 q1 - 2 q2) q2 Theta^(1 + 2 q1 + 2 q2))/((1 + 2 q1)! (2 q2)!), 
    {q1, 0, Infinity}, {q2, 0, Infinity}]]
```

I am basically summing the same coefficients, but in two different ways: one with two summations, the other with a summation over two indices. The results are the following:

```
1/2 Theta Sin[Theta/2]^2

-(1/4) Theta Cos[Theta]
```

As you can see they dont match. Why is it so?

To give some interpretation, it is actually the Taylor coefficient of sin(theta/2) * q1) * Taylor_coefficient(cos(theta/2)) * q2 * (-2 q2) that I integrate. Said differently, I am summing

```
-2 q2 Coeff[Sin[q1]] Coeff[Cos[q2]]
```

over `q1` and `q2` :

Comment: Last point is not clear. Can you please write more precisely how you get the series, either in mathematical form or a respective derivation with MA. The equation in orange box has no Theta.

Comment: You could substitute numerical values to find which gives the correct answer. Remember that it may not be mathematically legitimate to interchange the 2 limiting processes.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, just a long comment...

One can simplify this case to this:

```
expr = ( 2^(q1 + q2) q1)/((1 + 2 q1)! ( 2 q2)!);

Sum[expr, {q1, 0, Infinity}, {q2, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "IteratedSummation"] -
Sum[expr, {q1, 0, Infinity}, {q2, 0, Infinity}] // FullSimplify

(* 1/4 *)
```

Which more clearly specifies the discrepancy in two methods.

Comment: To understand: is it then a a problem of interversion of two series (thus a mathematical problem) behind ? I tried to look at what means "iterated univariate summation" but I didn't find something interesting yet.

Comment: @StarBucK I suspect it's a bug in `Automatic` method Wolfram uses to calculate this double sum. `IteratedSummation` is a method of just symbolically summing one sum and then another, like in your question `Sum[Sum[...],...]`